# Postfixing unary operators with parentheses

Tags: java

So hello guys, I have a new problem
x = square root, c = cos
How can I make: x ( ( 1 - c ( 30 ) ) / 2 ) to postfix: 1 30 c - 2 / x, it gives me this postfix: 1 30 2 / c - x

How can I convert the said infix to the said postfix? What precedence or associativity should I make it to? The infix of unary operators that I want to use in my program should be operator ( value ), I want it to have a parenthesis in between. Im trying to make a scientific sort of calculator that's why

EDIT: here's what I have, what should I change or make?

```
private static final int L_ASSOC = 0;
    private static final int R_ASSOC = 1;

    private static final Map<String, int[]> OP = new HashMap<String, int[]>();
    static {
        OP.put("+", new int[] { 0, L_ASSOC });
        OP.put("-", new int[] { 0, L_ASSOC });
        OP.put("*", new int[] { 5, L_ASSOC });   //Precedence, Associativity
        OP.put("/", new int[] { 5, L_ASSOC });
        OP.put("%", new int[] { 10, L_ASSOC });
                OP.put("x", new int[] { 10, R_ASSOC });
                OP.put("s", new int[] { 10, R_ASSOC });
                OP.put("c", new int[] { 10, R_ASSOC });
                OP.put("t", new int[] { 10, R_ASSOC });
        OP.put("^", new int[] { 10, R_ASSOC });
    }

    public static boolean IsASSOC(String Token, int Type){
                if (!IsOP(Token)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid token: " + Token);
            }
            if (OP.get(Token)[1] == Type) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
            }

        private static final int GetPrecedence(String T1, String T2) { 
            if (!IsOP(T1) || !IsOP(T2)) {       
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }

            return OP.get(T1)[0] - OP.get(T2)[0];
        }



            public static boolean IsOP(String Token){
                return OP.containsKey(Token);
            }

            public static String[] Infix2Postfix(String[] infix) {
                ArrayList<String> Postfix = new ArrayList<String>();
                Stack<String> OperatorStack = new Stack<String>();
                for ( String tkn: infix ){
                    if (IsOP(tkn)){
                        while (!OperatorStack.empty() && IsOP(OperatorStack.peek())) { 

                        if (( IsASSOC(tkn, L_ASSOC) && GetPrecedence(tkn, OperatorStack.peek()) <= 0 )
                                ||
                                               (IsASSOC(tkn, R_ASSOC) && GetPrecedence(tkn, OperatorStack.peek()) < 0)) 
                                            {
                            Postfix.add(OperatorStack.pop());
                            continue;
                        }       
                        break;
                    }

                    OperatorStack.push(tkn);
                } else if (tkn.equals("(")) {
                    OperatorStack.push(tkn);
                } else if (tkn.equals(")")) {

                    while (!OperatorStack.empty() && !OperatorStack.peek().equals("(")) {
                        Postfix.add(OperatorStack.pop());
                    }
                } else { 
                    Postfix.add(tkn); // [S12]
                }
            }
            while (!OperatorStack.empty()) { 

                            if (IsOP(OperatorStack.peek())==false){
                                String s = OperatorStack.pop();
                                continue;
                            }
                                Postfix.add(OperatorStack.pop()); 
            }
            String[] output = new String[Postfix.size()];
            return Postfix.toArray(output);
            }
```

MY SOLUTION:

```
 else if (tkn.equals(")")) {

                        while (!OperatorStack.empty() && !OperatorStack.peek().equals("(")) {
                            Postfix.add(OperatorStack.pop());
                        }
OperatorStack.pop(); //I Simply popped after the while loop to remove the matching open parenthesis
                    }
```

Comment: You should show us what you have tried, it will give us a better starting point for guiding you and will also help any suspicions that you are just trying to have us do your homework for you. Maybe at least you have code that works for binary operators (`-` and `/`) that you would want the solution to fit into.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. I've added the code

Comment: Your code would be so much easier to work with if you followed​ the Java naming conventions.

Comment: I'm new to java, what do you mean by that?

Comment: A method name should begin with a lowercase letter: `IsOP()` should be `isOp()`, `Infix2Postfix()` should be `infix2Postfix()`. Same for variables and parameters: `OP` should be `op`, `Token` should be `token`.

Comment: Okay thanks, I solved my problem too

Comment: Good for you, @Akuichi. If you think your solution may be helpful to others, please consider posting it as an answer. If not, please delete the question. The question isn’t really helpful to anyone as it stands now.

Comment: I don't know if my solution is helpful or not, but I'm adding the solution for now